# A web application appears to have started a thread named [22] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I have a web application with Servlets in the back end deployed over tomcat. The application is simple java application.

I see this error frequently in the server logs:
SEVERE: A web application appears to have started a thread named 
[22] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely 
to create a memory leak.

Are there any potential reasons which might be causing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use [visualvm 1.3.2](http://visualvm.java.net/relnotes.html) and see what threads are being created.  Be sure to add all the plug-ins.

If it's not being done by your code you won't have much control over it.

You also don't know if the message is a red herring or not.  Load test your code over a period of time and measure what happens.

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar situation recently Resolved in below steps

> 1. I took Thread dump. ( using Kill -QUIT pid )
> 2. Found the Runnable/Thread class form dump
> 3. Then i put a debug point in run method and started application in
>      debug mode.
> 4. Got the code which starts My Thread and I observed it was not
>      stopped while stoping application.
> 5. Introduced code to stop the thread in contextDestroyed method of
>      AppContextListener (This is My application class which extends
>      ServletContextListener ) as this method will be called when i stop
>      tomcat.

If you set Thread as Dameon Thread it is not going to help , you can visit [explanation](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection).

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat waits for all the application's threads (user threads not daemon threads) to stop before it goes down, I guess that in your case this specific thread is a user thread and therefore tomcat generated this error.
I suggest you to change this thread to daemon (assuming this one is yours)